# Use of unassigned local variable when trying to return bool

Tags: c#

So i need to return a variable that checks whether the date the user inputs falls between the 2 dates I given. For now I didn't do the user part.

I tried checking and returning a variable but the above error is given

```
public bool IsInPeakSeason(DateTime date)
    {
        DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2019, 06, 15);
        DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2019, 08, 15);
        DateTime dateCheck >= date1 && dateCheck <date;
        return date >= date1 && date < date2;
    }
```

I want to return either true or false if the date is either in between or not between the given dates

Comment: That warning is just telling you that you aren't making use of `dateCheck`

Comment: I am not sure how that even compiles? You are using the variable `dateCheck` in the declaration//assignment although there is no direct assignment even .

Comment: `DateTime dateCheck >= date1 && dateCheck <date;` - This line will not compile.

Comment: Just remove the `dateCheck` line and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is that you're attempting to use `dateCheck` in it's initial assignment, which is not allowed. In otherwords, you can't do something like `int number = number + 1;` because `number` on the right hand side of the assignment is not assigned yet. Of course the line in question must have some other typos in it, because it won't compile at all.

Regardless, you don't really need that line anyway (the variable isn't used anywhere else). If you remove it, your code should work as expected.

The one change I would make is to not hard-code the year portion but instead use the year specified in the `date` parameter. This way the method will work in future years. Even better would be to read the peak date ranges from some other data source, so they can be modified without having to recompile the code. But the basic idea I'm suggesting would look like this:

```
public bool IsInPeakSeason(DateTime date)
{
    var startPeak = new DateTime(date.Year, 06, 15);
    var endPeak = new DateTime(date.Year, 08, 15);
    return date >= startPeak && date < endPeak;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

as @frontear mentioned, the error is in regards to this line:
`DateTime dateCheck >= date1 && dateCheck <date;`

You are attempting to use `dateCheck` without having first assigning a value to it.  With the code below, you can omit `dateCheck` entirely like so, in a single line:

`return (date >= new DateTime(2019, 06, 15) && date <= new DateTime(2019, 08, 15));`

Comment: This only changes the method for creating a `DateTime`, except now you have hard-coded the month and day positions in a string, which is much less culture-aware. And the second option is basically the exact same as the OP's code, except the `dateCheck` variable assignment has been omitted. It would be more helpful if you described what the problem is and how this fixes it.

Comment: @RufusL revised.  Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Except the error is not stating that he did not use `dateCheck`, but rather that they attempted to use it before it was assigned...

Comment: @RufusL Oh, good call.  Nice catch -- missed it.  Revised answer once again